# Static IP to LoadBalancer service using k8s on aws (Allocation IDs)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb

It says use service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations' to assign AWS EIP to the newly created Network Load Balancer (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/69263). But, how to obtain AWS Allocation IDs?
At [unable to give static ip to nlb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282601/unable-to-give-static-ip-to-nlb),

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: "eipalloc- 
    07e3afcd4b7b5d644,eipalloc-0d9cb0154be5ab55d,eipalloc-0e4e5ec3df81aa3ea"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: "subnet- 
    061f4a497621a7179,subnet-001c2e5df9cc93960"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

How to get those eipalloc IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I think you would just create [Elastic IP's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) in AWS and then get their Allocation Id's either in the console or by [describing them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html) via the awscli.

```
AllocationId
[Network Load Balancers] The allocation ID of the Elastic IP address for an internet-facing load balancer.

Type: String

Required: No
```

[image]